# NopCommerce 3.7: Is there a way to get SubCategory products to show up on a parent Category page BUT grouped by the Sub Category?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Nop 3.7

Is there a way to get SubCategory products to show up on a parent Category page BUT grouped by the Sub Category?

Current code not working:

**ProductModel.cs (in the Nop.Web project)**

```
 public partial class SubCategoryModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public SubCategoryModel()
        {
            PictureModel = new PictureModel();
            //Custom ADDED PRODUCT LIST TO LIST OUT SUB CATERGORY PRODUCTS CORRECTLY
            Products = new List<ProductOverviewModel>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string SeName { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public PictureModel PictureModel { get; set; }
        //Custom ADDED PRODUCT LIST TO LIST OUT SUB CATERGORY PRODUCTS CORRECTLY
        public IList<ProductOverviewModel> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

**CSHTML (View in the Nop.Web project)**

```
    @*--Custom GET SUBCATEGORIES AND SHOW THEIR PRODUCTS UNDER EACH SUB CATEGORY--*@
        @if (Model.SubCategories.Count > 0)
        {
           <div id="customSubCategoriesWithProducts">
               <p>Custom stuff below:</p>
                @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
                { 
                    <div class="customSubCategorieSection">
                        <h2 class="title">
                                @item.Name

                        </h2>
                            @foreach (var product in item.Products)
                            { 
                               @product.Name  
  //No output when trying to get the products.  Is there a way to do this?
                            }

                    </div>
                }
           </div>

        }
```

Desired affect:

Parent Category Page

- SubCategory1

  [Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3]
- SubCategory2

  [Product 4], [Product 5], [Product 6]
  ...

Image of the desired outcome:
[image]

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? NC doesnt have it out of the box, I believe. you need program around a bit.

Comment: @batmaci is right ,If you want this then do customization.

Comment: Your variant of the code it is working. Tell me, you fill in the data model SubCategoryModel? Category name and the products they own? Or you simply create a class that is responsible for this?
If you do fill the data model is a good idea to give an example of code, how do you do

Comment: @Dmitry, I did not get the code working.   I actually just took the ProductModel.cs file that exists in NopCommerce and just tried to just copy and paste the public IList<ProductOverviewModel> Products { get; set; } lines directly into the SubCategoryModel().  I asked this question on NOpCommerce's forums too, but have not received an answer or suggestions yet, this is why I have come here.  If you have any pointers, I would be greatly appreciated, because I am not having any luck at all.